# Is the following the density of a Gaussian bivariate distribution? Can anyone help, please?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

My question is, can the following function:

$f(x, y) = \frac {1}{2π}exp(−0.5(x^2+xy))$

be the density of a Gaussian vector?

I do not think so, since $y^2$ does not even appear, and it looks like there is no correlation $\rho$ compatible with this distribution. Am I wrong or not?

**Edit, here is my attempt:**
If f(x,y) was the density of a gaussian vector, then: $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy = 1$ (But would this be sufficient? I do not think so.), then

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {1}{2π}exp(−0.5(x^2+xy))\  dxdy = \frac{1}{2π} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-0.5x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-0.5xy}\  dy $$

We can check that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-0.5xy}\ dy$$ is $+\infty$ if $x<0$, while $-\infty$ if $x>0$. So that the $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy $ diverges. Am I right??

Comment: The value of $x^2 + xy$ can be very negative, and therefore $f(x,y)$ can go up to $\infty$ ...

Comment: ok. but what are the parameters of the pdf? namely, $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$,$\sigma_1$,$\sigma_2$, $\rho$? It looks like to me we can not find them in a manner which is coherent with that of a bivariate gaussian pdf

Comment: The other comment is probably hinting that, $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy \neq 1$, so it cannot be a density.

Comment: To complement what @NapD.Lover said, a Gaussian density is bounded.

Comment: Thank you, can this integral $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy \neq 1$ solved using standard integration rules?

Comment: I would like to formally show that $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy \neq 1$. I have just edited my question including your hints. Can you help me with this please? Also, if I got that $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy = 1$, would this be sufficient to conclude that $f(x,y) were the density of a gaussian vector?

Comment: @LearningProb to answer the second part: no, showing normalization and (and having $f(x, y) \geq 0$, which is true here, of course) only says that $f$ is a valid PDF, but *not necessarily* a Gaussian PDF.  I will check your attempt at showing the integral diverges, I meant to comment on an argument for that but lost time.

Comment: Ok, thank you..

Comment: Sorry, I have only this question. We can say that $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dxdy \neq 1$ can not be a density for any vector$(X,Y)$, that has support $(-\infty,\infty)×(-\infty,\infty)$, but it may be the case that for random variables defined over a different support, $f(x,y)$ can be a density technically. Am I right?

Comment: @LearningProb yes, if you can find a region where the candidate density is normalized, then it’ll be the PDF of a RV with that region as its support. Sorry for never getting back to you originally but it looks like you got your work checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well forget the scaling factor (the thing multiplying your exponential) for a moment. A multivariate Gaussian distribution constitutes of the term
$$\exp \Big( -\frac{1}{2} (z-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (z-\mu) \Big)$$
where $\mu = 0$ (zero-mean) in your case and $z =[x,y]^T$. By inspection, we can note that 
$$\Sigma^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} &  0\end{bmatrix} $$
Note that $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix. We can see that $\Sigma^{-1}$ has a negative determinant, hence not a PSD (positive semi-definite). So, by contradiction, this is not a Gaussian distribution since a covariance matrix has to be PSD.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there is another way to show it? For instance, what is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: @LearningProb, nothing is wrong. Actually your function doesn't sum up to $1$. I don't think your argument is invalid. You are showing that the function is not even a PDF. I wanted to give you a bit more insight (since the function "looks" like a Gaussian one) on why it isn't Gaussian.

But in case your PDF sums up to something finite, say $A$. One can always jump and say "oh but you can divide the function by $A$ to make it a valid PDF".

Comment: yes the integral diverges for any $x$ @LearningProb

Comment: Sorry but, the entries of the inverse of the cov matrix can not be the ones you mentioned, because we obtain $x^2+2xy$ and not $x^2+xy$

Comment: you're right, allow me to edit @LearningProb .. but we still have a negative determinant.

Comment: Ok thank you. We may also notice that the element (2,2) of the inverse is 0 if and only if the variance of x is zero, so that X can not be normal. Is this correct?